# C++ template programming/STL deducing parameters

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to implement a serialization method for STL containers templated over primitive types.

How can I deduce, lets say, what key and value types are for lets say an unordered map so that I can implement the appropriate logic depending on the key/value type.

I know template metaprogramming is the way to do this but a concrete example will be much appreciated.

Comment: There are many, many examples of templated design scattered on the internet (C++ Template Example has 500,000+ google results). Please research on your own to get an better idea of what you are asking, as in its current state your question is very broad.

Comment: **RTFM**. That information is in the template definition.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be enough to jumpstart your project.  This super awesome JSON serializer uses function overloads to handle each data type to be serialized.  The `Serialize` overload for `unordered_map`, itself calls `Serialize` to serialize the key and value for each contained object.  New types can be supported by just adding new overloads.

I made a change to the `Serialize` overload, previously for `int`: Now it demonstrates how to use the type traits library so the compiler selects this overload for any arithmetic type, not just `int`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

std::string Serialize(std::string s) {
    return '"' + s + '"';
}

template <
    typename T, 
    typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type
>
std::string Serialize(T n) {
    return std::to_string(n);
}

template <typename Key, typename Val, typename ...Other>
std::string Serialize(typename std::unordered_map<Key, Val, Other...> const &um) {
    std::string result = "{";
    bool comma = false;
    for(const auto& kv : um) {
        if(comma) { result += ','; }
        else      { comma = true; }
        result += Serialize(kv.first);
        result += ':';
        result += Serialize(kv.second);
    }
    result += '}';
    return result;
}

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> mymap;
    mymap["one"] = 1;
    mymap["two"] = 2;

    auto serialized = Serialize(mymap);
    std::cout << serialized << '\n';
}
```

Output

```
{"two":2,"one":1}
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

Containers define `typedef` s that describe what's in them.

If `T` is a map, a multimap, a set, or a multiset, as well as their unordered flavors, just like you have a

```
 T::iterator
```

and

```
 T::const_iterator
```

you also have a

```
 T::key_type
```

and

```
 T::value_type
```

See the specification for each container for a full list of all the types it defines.

That's how you know what's in the container.